# Cannot Open InfoPath Form - DTD Prohibited

Tags: infopath, dtd

I have a browser-based InfoPath 2010 form.  I'm getting an error opening the form in one environment.  It works in at least three other environments.  The error is:

The form template failed to load... Type: XmlException, Exception Message: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

I have seen this question posted around the Web, but the answers are vague and varied and are centered around products besides InfoPath.  We also have other forms working in the environment where this form is failing, so it's something related to this particular form in this particular environment.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  The error message was misleading, but turns out one of the data connections had a URL pointing to the wrong SharePoint farm.  It was supposed to be pointing to the local form library.  Cross platform calls tend not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically make sure that the domain name in the connection file is matching the domain name where you're publishing your form.

For example, if your InfoPath form is located in:

```
 https://extranet.MySiteName.com/The-Rest-Of-Your-Domain-Name
```

then make sure that all the domains (in this example `extranet.MySiteName.com/`)
in your data connection file match. The connection file line may look similar to this:

```
<udc:Query> 
    https://extranet.MySiteName.com/_vti_bin/My-WCF-Services/My-Data-ServiceName.svc/
</udc:Query>
```